He regretted not having come more often to her. (nuance diffrence)

He regretted not having come more often to her.

vs.

He regretted not having gone more often to her.

Is there any difference between the two sentences? The only one is come vs. go.

Idiomatically, we're far more likely to put the prepositional phrase "to her" before the adverbial element: He regretted not having gone to her more often.

It's just a difference in perspectives.
Cambridge Dictionary says

We use come when we see things from the receiver’s viewpoint.
We use go when we see things from the doer’s viewpoint.

In the OP's first example, the speaker views himself or herself from her position.  For example, the speaker may be talking with people around her.  The second example has the speaker on the he side.
come or go

The sentence expresses a character's thought  ("his" thought) in the third person.
Where "he" is at the time of this thought would probably be the determining factor.
You would most likely find the "come" version in a   narrative when the thought passes through his mind while he is in her presence, or the "gone" version when he is back at his usual place.
It would be unlikely to find the "gone" version in a modern  narrative while he is in her presence, and just as unlikely to find the "come" version when he is back at his place.  If that were to happen, the perspective of the  third-person narrator comes into the foreground. That is not an impossibility, of course, but modern third-person narratives tend to express the perspective of the character.
